# componentWillReceiveProps() duplicates the elements from map

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
componentWillReceiveProps = (newProps) => {
        console.log("data ");

        let apiData = newProps.apiData;

        if (apiData.topProfiles && apiData.topProfiles.success) {
            let therapists = apiData.topProfiles.therapists
            let hasMore = true

            if (!therapists.length) {
                hasMore = false
            }

            this.setState(() => ({
                therapists: this.state.therapists.concat(therapists),
                hasMore: hasMore,
                pageLoading: false
            }))
        } else if (apiData.therapistsByName && apiData.therapistsByName.success) {
            let therapists = apiData.therapistsByName.therapists,
                resTitle = therapists.length ?
                    `Results for "${this.state.searchName}"`
                    : `Looks like there are no results for "${this.state.searchName}"`
            this.setState(() => ({
                therapists: therapists,
                hasMore: false,
                pageLoading: false,
                resultsTitle: resTitle
            }))
        }
```

I read about componentWillReceiveProps and is not safe anymore. How can I implement it much more efficient.
I have a function which render a list of therapists, but if I am in therapist pages where the content is rendered, and click on "Specialists" (button path) again in Header, the therapist list duplicates.

```
renderTherapists = () => {
        console.log("this state therapists: ", this.state.therapists)
        let items = this.state.therapists.map( (t, idx) => (
            <TherapistCard therapist={t} key={idx} />
        ))

        return (
            <div ref={0} className="therapist-list">
                { items }
            </div>
        )
    }
```

[console log after header button press](https://i.stack.imgur.com/onjbB.png)

Comment: Mmh, where is that 'Specialists' button and what does it do when you click on it? I see that sometimes, in `componentWillReceiveProps`, you are concatenating the list of therapists to the current list. I think this is the cause. I mean, componentWillReceiveProps will give you the new props, *all of them*, not just the modified ones.

Comment: `this.setState(() => ({
                therapists: this.state.therapists.concat(therapists),
                hasMore: hasMore,
                pageLoading: false
            }))`, here  `therapists: this.state.therapists.concat(therapists),`  you are concatenating array with array, this leads to duplicate. why dont you just replace the values, so you can avoid duplicate entry

Answer (score 0):

The code you have keeps concatenating therapists to the therapists array on the state because *componentWillReceiveProps* will run regardless if the props changed or not, as per [React documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops).

The real question is, should you store something in your state if it's already available as a prop. If you have a list of therapists as a prop, why not simply render it instead of duplicating it and having to keep those two in sync?

If you really have to keep it in the state for whatever reason, you can use [componentDidUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidupdate) in which you can compare equality of previous and current props and set the state accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compare the coming data with this.state.therapists state in componentWillReceiveProps before updating therapists state because every time componentWillReceiveProps is running and you concatenate even if the same data coming.